# Multiple Inserts in Temporary Table MYSQL

Tags: mysql, insert-into

Trying to execute 3 insert commands in MySQL temporary Table in Stored Procedure but select command shows only first insert was executed/inserted.

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OtDates (OtDatesList Date, TotalOTMinutes int);

#Fist Insert
    insert into OtDates(OtDatesList,TotalOTMinutes) values('2017-04-15', 400);
#Second Insert    
    insert into OtDates(OtDatesList,TotalOTMinutes) values(@DateOtHalf, @TotalOTMinutesHalf);
#Third Insert   
    insert into OtDates(OtDatesList,TotalOTMinutes) values(@DateOtFull, @TotalOTMinutesFull);
```

Select command returns only 2017-04-15, 400 while values from variables in 2nd and 3rd insert are not listed. If I remove the first insert command, the second one gets inserted and not the third one.

EDIT 2 :

Providing complete stored procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Test0`()
begin


select @DateOtHalf:=DateofIn, @TotalOTMinutesHalf:=TotalOTMinutes from hrtpunch where TotalOTMinutes >= @ExtraWorkHalfDayInMin and TotalOTMinutes < @ExtraWorkFullDayInMin and EmpID = P_EmpID;

select @DateOtFull:=DateofIn, @TotalOTMinutesFull:=TotalOTMinutes  from hrtpunch where TotalOTMinutes >= @ExtraWorkFullDayInMin and EmpID = P_EmpID;



CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OtDates (OtDatesList Date, TotalOTMinutes int);



#Fist Insert
    insert into OtDates(OtDatesList,TotalOTMinutes) values('2017-04-15', 400);
#Second Insert    
    insert into OtDates(OtDatesList,TotalOTMinutes) values(@DateOtHalf, @TotalOTMinutesHalf);
#Third Insert   
    insert into OtDates(OtDatesList,TotalOTMinutes) values(@DateOtFull, @TotalOTMinutesFull);

    select * from OtDates;


 end
```

EDIT 3 : Providing Sample Data and Table Structure from "hrtpunch"

Create Statement

```
CREATE TABLE `hrtpunch` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `TotalOTMinutes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=464 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Sample Data Insert

```
insert into hrtpunch (TotalOTMinutes) values(61);
insert into hrtpunch (TotalOTMinutes) values(600);
insert into hrtpunch (TotalOTMinutes) values(301);
insert into hrtpunch (TotalOTMinutes) values(0);
```

And Int Values returned for  ExtraWorkHalfDayInMin is 160 and ExtraWorkFullDayInMin is 240

Comment: How do you execute the inserts? Do you get any error message?

Comment: Forgot to mention, it is code part of a stored procedure. Updating the same in question description.

Comment: Again, is there any error message? Have you tried bulk insert syntax instead of issuing 3 separate inserts?

Comment: No error message. And I have not tried bulk insert,

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot reproduce the behaviour. You need to share the entire SP with us.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rLYnynSzHwXP56B6xBPsCp/2) example.

Comment: Please check Edit 2, it reproduces the scenario.

Comment: Interestingly, before sharing edit 2, I have also tried with static values and the problem vanished. But if variables are used that also called from the table, the problem persists, but if I remove the first Insert, the second insert works(of course even with variable values from the table) and similarly if I remove the first and second, the third insert works. Verified twice.

Comment: Pls try to assign values to the variables using `set` statements (@variable_name=(select ...) ), not in an explicit select ... The latter returns a resultset, which may interfere what you see in the results.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rLYnynSzHwXP56B6xBPsCp/3) example. Can you post the `hrtpunch` table structure and some sample data?.

Comment: @Shadow I have extensively tested and was working on same since posting this query, seems like you have found the route cause. I am getting a resultset in return but can't find a way to insert resultset in table beside using some loop by finding the count of resultset data.

Please suggest a way to insert resultset rows in table. Needless to say, I am begginer.

Comment: Similarly to @wchiquito I cannot reproduce the issue you are facing.

Comment: See updated [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rLYnynSzHwXP56B6xBPsCp/4).

Comment: @wchiquito, it is Inserting just first rows of the select query, for clear verification of this statement, please note the last 2 new insert statement in hrtpunch, the inserted value satisfies the conditions of Second select statement with >= operator, but is not listed in the result select statement.

Comment: @Shadow, it started inserting 1st row from both select statements as in wchiquito's [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rLYnynSzHwXP56B6xBPsCp/4) as  Limit 1 is used, but as already highlighted by you, if we don't use Limit 1 in select query, it will return a resultset with more than 1 row, & the original problem re-surfaces. 

So to my understanding, using some way to insert all rows of select statement 1-by-1will get it solved, I can try to do it using a loop which runs till the count of rows of resultset returned from select statement, but that doesn't seem to be the proper way.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OtDates (OtDatesList Date, TotalOTMinutes int);

INSERT INTO OtDates (OtDatesList,TotalOTMinutes) VALUES
('2017-04-15', 400), (@DateOtHalf, @TotalOTMinutesHalf), (@DateOtHalf, @TotalOTMinutesHalf)
```

**EDIT:**

For SQL 2005, the code above doesn't work, so try this:

```
INSERT INTO OtDates (OtDatesList,TotalOTMinutes)
SELECT '2017-04-15', 400
UNION ALL
SELECT @DateOtHalf, @TotalOTMinutesHalf
UNION ALL
SELECT @DateOtHalf, @TotalOTMinutesHalf
```

Comment: Tested, still getting results only from the first block of insert.

Comment: @ShubhamPandey I've edited my answer, please try the code on edit

Comment: Checked, Didn't work. I am updating the question with more detail as required by others.

Comment: The question is for MySQL, not ms sql server.

Comment: tested by converting the given code to single line though, no syntax error on MySQL, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `OtDates`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OtDates (OtDatesList Date, TotalOTMinutes int);

    insert into OtDates(OtDatesList,TotalOTMinutes) select @DateOtHalf:=DateofIn, @TotalOTMinutesHalf:=TotalOTMinutes from hrtpunch where TotalOTMinutes >= @ExtraWorkHalfDayInMin and TotalOTMinutes < @ExtraWorkFullDayInMin and EmpID = P_EmpID;



    insert into OtDates(OtDatesList,TotalOTMinutes) select @DateOtFull:=DateofIn, @TotalOTMinutesFull:=TotalOTMinutes  from hrtpunch where TotalOTMinutes >= @ExtraWorkFullDayInMin and EmpID = P_EmpID;
```

Comment: You can remove the assignment of [10.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) in your queries. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rLYnynSzHwXP56B6xBPsCp/8).